# Define FileField upload_to directory in Django model

Tags: django, database, filefield

I have a model Audiopart with field

```
filename = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)
```

and function for generating upload path

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(
        'audio',
        instance.book_id.folder,
        filename
    )
```

So file uploads to directory (for ex. "audio\mybook\a1.mp3"), that's good. And in database in field "filename" stores path "audio\mybook\a1.mp3".

Is any way to save in DB just filename "a1.mp3", without "audio\mybook\"?

Comment: do you want to show file name in frontend somewhere ?

Comment: I'm print objects in JSON   
all_audioparts = list(Audiopart.objects.values('id', 'book_id', 'part_title', 'filename', 'listened', 'length', 'part_reader'))

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can store that as well.

In the request payload, add the `filename` field that will be sent from FE (As they have filename as their end). Use that field as a original file name.

Hope this help. !!

Comment: Sorry, not understand you. I upload files from django admin panel. I should change my models file? What changes need to do?